# Powershell to send mail

Tags: powershell, email, sendmail

**Error**

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the
>   argument count: "2". At D:\Scripts\gsend.ps1:12 char:15

**Code**

```
#Create Password File (Only need once)
#$Credential = Get-Credential
#$Credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content "D:\scripts\gsendcred.txt" 

#Send Email

$EncryptedCredential = "D:\scripts\gsendcred.txt"

$EmailUsername = "me@gmail.com"

$EncryptedPW = Get-Content "D:\scripts\gsendcred.txt"

$EncryptedCredential = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptedCredential -
AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($EmailUsername, 
$EncryptedPW)

$EmailFrom = "me@gmail.com"

$EmailTo = "me@gmail.com"

$EmailSubject = "GSEND Test Subject"

$EmailBody = "Test Body"

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$SMTPPort = 587

$SMTPSsl = $true
```

Comment: Here is the error I receive: New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".
At D:\Scripts\gsend.ps1:12 char:15

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this content before you post anything more to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Use your $EncryptedCredential instead of $EncryptedPW, the PSCredential Object needs a SecureString

Comment: Cannot find overload means that what you put inside the parenthesis isn't what the method is looking for. So that means that something is wrong with `$EmailUsername` or `$EncryptedPW`. As Olaf says, this PSCredentials takes a string username and secure string password. `$EncryptedPW` isn't a secure string.

Comment: Changing to EncryptedCredential runs without errors now. The email does not send though. I added $param to the bottom of the script and and it errors out. (SIDE NOTE NEWBIE HERE to PowerShell). Here is what I added to the bottom:   
$param = @{SmtpServer = $SMTPServerPort = $SMTPPort, $UseSsl = $SMTPSsl, $Credential = $Credential $From = $EmailFrom $To = $EmailTo $Subject = $EmailSubject $Body = $EmailBody $Attachments = $EmailAttachments} Send-MailMessage @param

Comment: Ran more tests trying to stop the error. Have done that now. The script runs again without errors but does not send email. I changed the param to be: $param = @{
    $SMTPServer = $SMTPServer
    $SMTPServerPort = $SMTPPort
    $UseSsl = $SMTPSsl
    $Credential = $Credential
    $From = $EmailFrom
    $To = $EmailTo
    $Subject = $EmailSubject
    $Body = $EmailBody
    #$Attachments = $EmailAttachments
    }

"Send-MailMessage" 
$param

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is handling credentials. Here is how I handle the smtp credentials:

```
$smtpPwd = "password"
$smtpCredentialsUsername = "jdonnelly@xxxxx.com"
$smtpCredentialsPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $smtpPwd -AsPlainText -Force

 $Credentials = New-Object –TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential 
    –ArgumentList $smtpCredentialsUsername, $smtpCredentialsPassword
```

Then:

```
  $smtp.Credentials = $Credentials
```

Or if you are using Send-MailMessage store your email credentials locally by running this short script by itself beforehand:

```
Get-Credential | Export-Clixml C:\fso\myemailcreds.xml
```

It will prompt you to enter your credentials and then store them locally in (in this case) a folder called fso. Then in any Send-MailMessage cmdlet use the locally stored credentials as follows:

```
Send-MailMessage -To 'Recipient <recipient@yahoo.com>' -from 'John Donnelly <jdonnelly@xxx.com>' 
    -cc 'whoever <whoever@xxx.com>' -Subject $subject -Body $body 
    -BodyAsHtml -smtpserver "smtp.office365.com" -usessl 
    -Credential (Import-Clixml C:\fso\myemailcreds.xml) -Port 587
```

Comment: Thanks John, but it still doesn't correct my issue with my own script. Mail still does not go out

Comment: Can you post the entire script?

Comment: John, below is the script:

Comment: #Create Password File (Only need once)
#$Credential = Get-Credential
#$Credential.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content "D:\scripts\gsendcred.txt" 

#Send Email

$EncryptedCredential = "D:\scripts\gsendcred.txt"

$EmailUsername = "me@gmail.com"

$EncryptedPW = Get-Content "D:\scripts\gsendcred.txt"

$EncryptedCredential = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptedCredential -
AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential ($EmailUsername, 
$EncryptedPW)

$EmailFrom = "me@gmail.com"

$EmailTo = "me@gmail.com"

Comment: $EmailSubject = "GSEND Test Subject"

$EmailBody = "Test Body"

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$SMTPPort = 587

$SMTPSsl = $true

Comment: $param = @{
    $SMTPServer = $SMTPServer
    $SMTPServerPort = $SMTPPort
    $UseSsl = $SMTPSsl
    $Credential = $Credential
    $EmailFrom = $EmailFrom
    $EmailTo = $EmailTo
    $EmailSubject = $EmailSubject
    $EmailBody = $EmailBody
    #$Attachments = $EmailAttachments
    }

"Send-MailMessage" 
$param

Comment: It looks like the right bracket is commented out by the # in front of #$Attachments, You also are not using the proper key in your params splatting operation.

Comment: You are going through a lot to create your credentials. I suggest you use `Export-Clixml` and `Import-Clixml` as I outlined above.

Comment: Your $params should look like this: `@{'key1'='value1';'key2'='value2'}` so yours would be `$params = @{'smtpserver'=$SMTPServer, 'port'=$SMTPServerPort, 'credential'=$Credential, 'body'=$EmailBody etc }`. Try fixing the `$params` and remove that last `#`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use below Powershell script for send mail

Send-MailMessage -To "abc@abc.com" -From "def@abc.com" -Cc "gef@abc.com","hij@abc.com" -Subject Test Mail -BodyAsHtml $htmlbody  -SmtpServer "mailhost.abc.com"

where $htmlbody is string variable that contain html.